# ROracle, ошибка ORA-30204: buffer is not large enougth

Tags: oracle, r

Соединяем R c Oracle с использованием библиотеки ROracle.
Некоторые запросы отрабатывают без проблем. Но большинство запросов на select вылетает с ошибкой
ORA-30204: buffer is not large enougth.

Эти же запросы в SQL Developer отрабатывают без ошибок.
Ранее пользовались библиотекой RJDBC. Работает она существенно медленней, но запросы отрабатывают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от появившейся ошибки.

Comment: Как вы делаете select используете dbGetQuery? посмотрите на параметры bulk_read

Comment: Использовали dbGetQuery. Эксперименты с опцией bulk_read к успеху не привели. Да и dbSendQuery, собственно, вылетает с той же ошибкой.

Comment: А если при этом попробовать поставить prefetch = TRUE в dbconnect ?

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий. Учтем, если столкнемся с чем-то подобным в будущем.

Answer (score 3):

Решение оказалось там, где никто не подумал бы его искать. Ошибку ORA-30204 создавало наличие русскоязычного комментария в тексте SQL запроса. После удаления русскоязычных комментариев запросы стали работать. Т.е. нужно либо менять настройки кодировки, либо отказываться от кириллицы.